# How do I find which set of functions is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Choose the correct set of functions, which are not linearly independent.
>
> 1. $x^2-1$, $2x^2-x+1$, $3x^2-x$
> 2. $1$, $\tan x$, $\cot x$
> 3. $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$
> 4. $\sin^2 x$, $\cos^2 x$, $\sin 2x$

I thought of adding two terms together to get another term. But how do I check if they are linearly dependent or independent?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$3x^2-x-(x^2-1)=2x^2-x+1$

so the first set of vectors is linearly dependent.

For the rest find the [Wronskian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wronskian.html)

For example

$W(x^2,x^3,x^4)=6x^6$, thus the set $\{x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $x\neq0$.

and have a look at , for example, [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Algebra-Serge-Lang/dp/0387964126/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1420803239&sr=1-1&keywords=9780387964126)  or [this link](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~volds/math030notes/Unit20.pdf) if you would like to learn   more.

Comment: but linearly dependent means what is the exact definition??plz post if u know

Comment: a set of vectors are linearly dependent if and only if one of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of the others.

Comment: ok thank u so much sir...am a gate aspirant.if i have doubts,i surely ask u will not mention i think so sir...

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: and how do you prove that all other are not linear dependent?

Comment: @miracle173 thank you, I edited my answer. At the first time, the reason I only mentioned that the first set is linearly dependent and did not say anything about the rest I thought about the question as a multiple choice question.